# Array of images not working, while text in this is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, slidetoggle

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<style>
#wss{
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
transition:opacity 1.0s linear 0s;
  }
 </style>
 <script>
 var wss_i = 0;
```

This array is not working with images but it is working with text i dont whats wrong in it?

```
var wss_array = [
              "<img src="http://www.seizedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/e-Commerce-Logo.jpg" /> ",
              "<img src"http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/ff5b7cde-a0bb-4456-93ca-1014f25c063e/58300efe-0336-4287-9ad8-6555e8a9e6c1.jpg"/>",
              "<img src"http://www.golden-gate-park.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/conservatory_of_flowers3.jpg"/>",
              "<img src"http://www.robertashton.co.uk/communities/4/004/012/729/184/images/4619952637.jpg"/>",
              ];
   var wss_elem;
   function wssNext(){
    wss_i++;
   wss_elem.style.opacity = 0;
   if(wss_i > (wss_array.length - 1)){
    wss_i = 0;
 }
  setTimeout('wssSlide()',1000);
 }
 function wssSlide(){
 wss_elem.innerHTML = wss_array[wss_i];
 wss_elem.style.opacity = 1;
 setTimeout('wssNext()',2000);
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="wss"></span>
<script>wss_elem = document.getElementById("wss"); wssSlide(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: escape the attribute src of the images like that: **src=\"**

Comment: You need to learn to escape special chars because is a problem that you will have a lot of times. If you start a string with `"` , the next `"` that you write ends this string. to solve it you need to think where is fine to put `"` double quotes or `'` single quotes. If you need to mix it, you need to escape `\"`. Good luck

Comment: its not working with it @WashingtonGuedes

Comment: @deepsingh could you explain 'its not working' ?  maybe add a stack trace ?

Comment: what explaination u want... the array that contain images is not working.

Comment: thankew sir @MarcosPérezGude.... now i understand the concept of this.

Comment: Change this line to: _setTimeout(wssSlide,1000);_ and use: _var wss_i;_ before your function.

Comment: @deepsingh your ironic mode is childlike. But your code is cruft.

Comment: i am just a beginer @MarcosPérezGude and please guide with better code for this stuff.... i will be thankful .. if u guide me.

Comment: Ok, I think that you're ironic with me. I help you when you need it. So contact me when you have a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use escape sequence `\` in array for  `"`

```
var wss_array = [
              "<img src=\"http://www.seizedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/e-Commerce-Logo.jpg\" /> ",
              "<img src=\"http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/ff5b7cde-a0bb-4456-93ca-1014f25c063e/58300efe-0336-4287-9ad8-6555e8a9e6c1.jpg\"/>",

              ];
```

Comment: or simply a single quote `'`

Comment: tell me how single quata ' @AminJafari

Comment: like this `var wss_array = ['<img src="http://www.seizedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/e-Commerce-Logo.jpg" /> ', '<img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/ff5b7cde-a0bb-4456-93ca-1014f25c063e/58300efe-0336-4287-9ad8-6555e8a9e6c1.jpg"/>'];`